# D-Link SharePort USB Network Utilty on Windows 8

Tags: networking, troubleshooting

I'm just installed D-link's SharePort software on my fresh Windows 8. Installation went well, but won't start even after rebooting the os.
I have tried to run in compatibility mode, alse.

Does someone know how could I make it working?
The version I'm using: SharePort v1.17B01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, tried versions 3.x and 4.x of SP (and 1.14 as well). 1.x works as you've described and later versions install and run but don't find any SP "server".

To conclude, 1.17b01 goes well with my other PC with Windows 7 on board, so the problem was the software.

I found `ftp://ftp.dlink.pl/software/SharePortClient_sw_revNA_1-20_eu_multi_20121126.zip` – this works okay with Windows 8, at least for me.

Comment: As I wrote in the question I already used that version. However I've long forgot this thread and I figured out what was wrong. (I've included in your post.)

Comment: For future visitors, what the OP [suggested adding](http://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/95990) to the above answer (but which was rejected): *"Sometimes Windows versions can't reach the connected USB drive for some reasons. It helped to remove the cable and plug back in to the router after a few seconds. (This happens both Windows 7 and Windows 8)"*

Answer (score 0):

With [this version of shareport](http://www.dlinkla.com.co/sites/default/files/archivos/DIR-655/SharePort_1.20_Windows.zip), I have achieved to use my printer via shareport in Windows 8.1.